# I want to see the value when i press particular number button in django

Tags: python, html, django, view

I have a small Django calculator app. I want to display the value in the text box when any number button clicked

## My- HTML code

```
 <form action ="buttonClicked" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="calculator">

        <input type="text" class="calculator-screen" value="0" disabled name = "text-box"/>

        <div class="calculator-keys">

          <button type="button" class="operator" value="+">+</button>
          <button type="button" class="operator" value="-">-</button>
          <button type="button" class="operator" value="*">&times;</button>
          <button type="button" class="operator" value="/">&divide;</button>

          <button type="button" value="7">7</button>
          <button type="button" value="8">8</button>
          <button type="button" value="9">9</button>


          <button type="button" value="4">4</button>
          <button type="button" value="5">5</button>
          <button type="button" value="6">6</button>


          <button type="submit" value="1" name="btn1">1</button>
          <button type="button" value="2">2</button>
          <button type="button" value="3">3</button>


          <button type="button" value="0">0</button>
          <button type="button" class="decimal" value=".">.</button>
          <button type="button" class="all-clear" value="all-clear">AC</button>

          <button type="button" class="equal-sign" value="=">=</button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

## My view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import messages

    def calc(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
           #here i want to take the button value and display it on text box
        return render(request, 'Calculator.html')
```

## [Calc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoiNI.png)

if i press button 1 then it should display 1 in the text box...
how can i do that?

## Solved my problem

## View.py

```
def calc(request):
        if(request.POST.get('btn1')):

                print('Button clicked')
                return render(request, 'Calculator.html',{'val':100})
        else:
                return render(request, 'Calculator.html',{'val':0})
```

Comment: use J-query to set input value

Comment: I just want to use python to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can see the value, but if you give the button a name you can check if it is in the POST.  For example:

```
    <div class="calculator-keys">

      <button type="button" class="operator" value="+" name="btn_plus">+</button>
      <button type="button" class="operator" value="-" name="btn_minus">-</button>
      <button type="button" class="operator" value="*" name="btn_times">&times;</button>
      <button type="button" class="operator" value="/" name="btn_divide">&divide;</button>
    </div>
```

Then within the view:

```
if 'btn_plus' in request.POST: ...
```

etc

Comment: I can be able to check with the logic you gave. but I want to see that value in the text box. I don't know exactly how to pass a value to textbox